# Empty dataframe falsely generated by groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('time_interval')).idxmin()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing the task of finding the exact time at which a measured value within a time series is minimal within equidistant time intervals of the time series.

I tried to use `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('time_interval')).idxmin()` to perform this task, but I encounter a unexpected (maybe wrong) behaviour of this method:
When using the `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('time_interval')).idxmin()` method on a dataframe with datetime indices which contains (at least) one interval between two rows that is larger than the resample interval, it generates a completely empty dataframe instead of filling the additional intervals with 'NaT' (like `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('time_interval')).xmin()` fills the additional intervals with 'NaN').
Does anybody knows a workaround for this problem (or is there maybe a bugfix for this method)? I put a minimal working example with some inline discussion at the end of the post.

Cheers,

Simon

python version: Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)

pandas version: 0.19.2

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

timestamp_list = [1493992554.897, 1493999093.997, 1493999108.733, 1493999116.101, 1493999117.943, 1493999119.785, 1493999121.627, 1493999123.469, 1493999125.311, 1493999127.153, 1493999128.995, 1493999130.837, 1493999132.679, 1493999134.521, 1493999136.363, 1493999138.205, 1493999140.047, 1493999141.889, 1493999143.731, 1493999145.573, 1493999147.415, 1493999149.257, 1493999151.099, 1493999152.941, 1493999154.783, 1493999156.625, 1493999158.467, 1493999160.309, 1493999162.151, 1493999163.993]
value_list = [2.52962e-41, 2.52962e-41, 11.9625, 12.033420000000001, 12.069, 12.0784, 12.080933333333334, 12.080549999999999, 12.080233333333332, 12.078975, 12.033750000000001, 11.9472, 11.910966666666667, 11.902700000000001, 11.899766666666666, 11.898925, 11.898733333333332, 11.8987, 11.921174999999998, 11.982775, 12.010975000000002, 12.019466666666666, 12.021700000000001, 12.0224, 12.0225, 12.0226, 11.95525, 11.776133333333334, 11.65815, 11.624400000000001]

dt_list = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x) for x in timestamp_list]

time_frame =  pd.DataFrame(index=dt_list, data=value_list)
time_frame.columns = ['value']

time_frame.head()
# Out[11]:
#                                value
# 2017-05-05 15:55:54.897  2.529620e-41  <- Large time diff (larger than resample length)
# 2017-05-05 17:44:53.997  2.529620e-41  <-
# 2017-05-05 17:45:08.733  1.196250e+01
# 2017-05-05 17:45:16.101  1.203342e+01
# 2017-05-05 17:45:17.943  1.206900e+01

# I want to resample this dataframe and determine the min in each interval
# this works fine:

tf_resampled_min = time_frame.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('60000L')).min()
tf_resampled_min.head()

#Out[13]:    
#                        value
#2017-05-05 15:55:00  2.529620e-41
#2017-05-05 15:56:00           NaN
#2017-05-05 15:57:00           NaN
#2017-05-05 15:58:00           NaN
#2017-05-05 15:59:00           NaN

# I also want to determine the exact time the mmin occured, and here I encounter a problem:

tf_resampled_idxmin = time_frame.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('60000L')).idxmin()
tf_resampled_idxmin.head()

#Out[14]:
#Empty DataFrame
#Columns: []
#Index: []

# I expected something like:
#                        
#2017-05-05 15:55:00  2017-05-05 15:55:54.897
#2017-05-05 15:56:00           NaT
#2017-05-05 15:57:00           NaT
#2017-05-05 15:58:00           NaT
#2017-05-05 15:59:00           NaT

# With this output I would still be able to determine the minidx in the valid regions, but with the empty dataframe, all information is lost.

# The Problem is indeed the time gap between the first two entries. If I remove them, I get:

timestamp_list2 = [1493999093.997, 1493999108.733, 1493999116.101, 1493999117.943, 1493999119.785, 1493999121.627, 1493999123.469, 1493999125.311, 1493999127.153, 1493999128.995, 1493999130.837, 1493999132.679, 1493999134.521, 1493999136.363, 1493999138.205, 1493999140.047, 1493999141.889, 1493999143.731, 1493999145.573, 1493999147.415, 1493999149.257, 1493999151.099, 1493999152.941, 1493999154.783, 1493999156.625, 1493999158.467, 1493999160.309, 1493999162.151, 1493999163.993]
value_list2 = [2.52962e-41, 11.9625, 12.033420000000001, 12.069, 12.0784, 12.080933333333334, 12.080549999999999, 12.080233333333332, 12.078975, 12.033750000000001, 11.9472, 11.910966666666667, 11.902700000000001, 11.899766666666666, 11.898925, 11.898733333333332, 11.8987, 11.921174999999998, 11.982775, 12.010975000000002, 12.019466666666666, 12.021700000000001, 12.0224, 12.0225, 12.0226, 11.95525, 11.776133333333334, 11.65815, 11.624400000000001]

dt_list2 = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x) for x in timestamp_list2]
time_frame2 =  pd.DataFrame(index=dt_list2, data=value_list2)
time_frame2.columns = ['value']

tf_resampled_idxmin2 = time_frame2.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('60000L')).idxmin()
tf_resampled_idxmin2.head()

#Out[20]:
#                                      value
#2017-05-05 17:44:00 2017-05-05 17:44:53.997
#2017-05-05 17:45:00 2017-05-05 17:45:41.889
#2017-05-05 17:46:00 2017-05-05 17:46:03.993
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for the problem:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

timestamp_list = [1493992554.897, 1493999093.997, 1493999108.733, 1493999116.101, 1493999117.943, 1493999119.785, 1493999121.627, 1493999123.469, 1493999125.311, 1493999127.153, 1493999128.995, 1493999130.837, 1493999132.679, 1493999134.521, 1493999136.363, 1493999138.205, 1493999140.047, 1493999141.889, 1493999143.731, 1493999145.573, 1493999147.415, 1493999149.257, 1493999151.099, 1493999152.941, 1493999154.783, 1493999156.625, 1493999158.467, 1493999160.309, 1493999162.151, 1493999163.993]
value_list = [2.52962e-41, 2.52962e-41, 11.9625, 12.033420000000001, 12.069, 12.0784, 12.080933333333334, 12.080549999999999, 12.080233333333332, 12.078975, 12.033750000000001, 11.9472, 11.910966666666667, 11.902700000000001, 11.899766666666666, 11.898925, 11.898733333333332, 11.8987, 11.921174999999998, 11.982775, 12.010975000000002, 12.019466666666666, 12.021700000000001, 12.0224, 12.0225, 12.0226, 11.95525, 11.776133333333334, 11.65815, 11.624400000000001]

dt_list = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x) for x in timestamp_list]

time_frame =  pd.DataFrame(index=dt_list, data=value_list)
time_frame.columns = ['value']

tf_resampled_idxmin = time_frame.resample("60000L").agg([lambda x: np.argmin(x) if len(x) > 0 else np.datetime64('NaT')])
print(tf_resampled_idxmin)

#                                  value
#                               <lambda>
#2017-05-05 15:55:00 2017-05-05 15:55:54.897
#2017-05-05 15:56:00                     NaT
#2017-05-05 16:23:00                     NaT
#2017-05-05 16:24:00                     NaT
#...                                     ...
#2017-05-05 17:17:00                     NaT
#2017-05-05 17:18:00                     NaT
#2017-05-05 17:43:00                     NaT
#2017-05-05 17:44:00 2017-05-05 17:44:53.997
#2017-05-05 17:45:00 2017-05-05 17:45:41.889
#2017-05-05 17:46:00 2017-05-05 17:46:03.993
```

The trick is to implement an own version of idxmin() with .agg([np.argmin()]) and a lambda function to catch the case of an empty list.